# Comparing product definitions in well-pointed categories vs general categories

Tags: category-theory, intuition, products

I'm new to category theory and trying to convince myself that the definition of a product makes sense. Ultimately my question is: in what sense does the category theory definition of a product generalize the usual definition? What is the intuition? The rest is an explanation of what I've tried so far:

In an [introduction I was looking at](https://www.logicmatters.net/resources/pdfs/GentleIntro.pdf) (ch. 7), it uses the notion of a well-pointed category to convert talk about elements to talk about arrows. So a product of $X$ and $Y$ is an object $O$ and arrows $\pi_1: O \rightarrow X$ and $\pi_2: O \rightarrow Y$ such that for any two arrows $\overrightarrow{x}: 1 \rightarrow X$ and $\overrightarrow{y}: 1 \rightarrow Y$ for a terminal object $1$ (in **Set**, just a singleton), there is a unique $\overrightarrow{u}: 1 \rightarrow O$ such that this diagram commutes:

[image]

So I understand this as for any pair of elements $x \in X$ and $y \in Y$, there is a unique $u \in O$ that projects on to both of them. The arrows pick out the elements. That makes sense to me. Then we jump to the general definition, which works in any category: $[O, \pi_1, \pi_2]$ is a product of $X$ and $Y$ iff for every $S$, $f_1:S \rightarrow X$, and $f_2:S \rightarrow Y$, there is a unique $u:S\rightarrow O$ such that this diagram commutes:

[image]

I don't really understand why we can just do that. I think it would be illuminating to see a proof that if $[O, \pi_1, \pi_2]$ is a product in the well-pointed sense, then it must be a product in the general sense. I've attempted it, but I keep getting stuck. I keep staring at this diagram:

[image]

I'm trying to convince myself that a $u$ that makes the diagram commute exists and is unique if I assume the rest of the diagram commutes, but I feel like I'm missing something. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Well, you know where $u$ must send every point of $S$, right?

Comment: @KevinCarlson If it were just a set and the usual ordered pairs, make $u(s) = (f_1(s), f_2(s))$. But I feel like I don't know the internal structure of $O$ in a general category. Or am I just going in circles for no reason?

Comment: Just write $\pi_i \circ u\circ s=f_i\circ s$, which uniquely determines $u\circ s$. Unfortunately as Malice says this only determines $u$ under a stronger form of well pointedness which is extremely rare.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The text is not claiming that the universal property of the second diagram is a consequence of the first; such an assertion is not generally true, even in the well-pointed case (see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/42222/do-functions-defined-on-global-elements-give-rise-to-arrows-in-a-well-pointed-to) for a counterexample).

It is rather expressing a more general *definition* of a product, so there is nothing to be proved here. Smith himself alludes to the fact that a definition in terms of points doesn't give you much in, for instance, the category $\mathbf{Grp}$ (every group is a product of any two groups in that sense). But the direct product of groups *does* satisfy the latter, more general form in non-trivial ways.

In case it helps to get the intuition, let's look at the category of sets, where the property expressed in the first diagram *does* imply the more general property. In $\mathbf{Set}$ every $x\in S$ corresponds to a unique point (once we pick a particular terminal object) $p_x:1\to S$. In $\mathbf{Set}$, any $S$-indexed family of points $i_x:1\to T$ will induce a function $i:S\to T$ with $i\circ p_x=i_x$ (this is a much stronger condition than Smith supposes, that $1$ is a *dense* generator). So in particular, any $S$-indexed family $u_x:1\to A\times B$ will give rise to a function $u:S\to A\times B$, but also two other $S$-indexed families $$\pi_1u_x:1\to A,\:\pi_2u_x:1\to B,$$ that then correspond to two maps $a:S\to A,\:b:S\to B$ with $ap_x=\pi_1u_x$ and $bp_x=\pi_2u_x$. In this special case you can check that $a,b$ are uniquely determined by the $u_x$ and vice versa.

But again, the situation I've described for $\mathbf{Set}$ is a very rare one. In general, you can't hope to infer that $O$ has the universal property in the second sense from it having it in the special case of maps from $1$.

Comment: Thank you, this helps. It also explains why I always felt like I was missing an arrow. In order to have it, I would need $1$ to be a dense generator.